# How do I change color of selected stars from a jquery rating plugin?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I used a jquery plugin to display a star rating from [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Highly-Customizable-Rating-Plugin-jQuery-Rateit-js.html).
The stars are displaying fine , however on selecting the stars, the selected color is red by default. the select color is in `.rateit .rateit-selected` class. I changed it to a yellow color in my **style.css** file

```
.rateit .rateit-selected {
color: rgb(239, 197, 41);
}
```

however, the color of the select has not changed and it seems that in the styling , its got a background gif right here [image: background gif of stars]

the full customization of the selected stars is a background of star.gif which is included with the plugin and a color of red ( which I changed to yellow).

```
.rateit .rateit-selected {
background : url(star.gif) left -16px;
color: rgb(239, 197, 41);
}
```

I'm not sure how do I customize the yellow color on select from star.gif , since it's got 4 different layers of stars in the gif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last value in the `background` CSS shorthand you're using is the vertical offset of the image. It's currently set to `-16px` which means that the image is raised 16px so that instead of displaying the default grey star which is at the top of the image, the red star is displayed instead.

If you want to show the yellow star, change the value to `-32px` to move the image up further:

```css
.rateit > div {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

.rateit .rateit-selected {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg6ov.gif) left -32px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="rateit">
  <div class="rateit-selected"></div>
</div>
```